# How to dehydrate nuts using an oven for a short time?

Tags: nuts, dehydrating

- The websites say after soaking nuts, I can dehydrate them using oven on low heat for 12 hours.
- But can I do it using higher heat for 1 hr only?
- and what would happen if I store nuts when they are not completely dried?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you soak them and then dry them?

Comment: several websites suggest that it improves the taste and activates the nutrients to be more absorbable.

Comment: soaking improves the nutrient availability, but won't dehydrating after that negate / reverse the benefits?

Answer (score 3):

Dehydration (low heat, long time) and cooking (high heat, generally shorter) are two separate things. Dehydration lowers the water content, whereas cooking changes the chemical structures in the food but may also dehydrate to a greater or lesser extent.

To dehydrate you need to gently heat for a longer time so that the water evaporates without cooking the nuts.

Higher heat for shorter times may or may not dehydrate depending on the temperature - you run the risk of burning or cooking the exterior making a soft interior and hardened shell. This may result in the interior of the nut potentially being able to grow any contaminating fungus or bacterium, which you might not be able to tell from the outside.

Comment: I don't know if it would help with nuts, but for home dried chilies, I've learned to put them in a glass jar, and leave them where you can watch them for a day or two -- if you see condensation on the inside of the jar, then they're not dry enough.